# AngularJS and JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have my simple HTML-file and JSON-file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="aboutController">
        <p ng-repeat="post in about">
            {{name.about}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('about.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.about = data;
                console.log('this is data:',data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
{
    "name" : "Peter",
    "surname" : "Chpoksky"
}
```

I need to transfer data from a json-file, but for some reason, the browser displays nothing
what is the problem?

Comment: What do you want to display exactly?

Comment: @myros.092, `{{name.about}}` should probably be `{{about.name}}`. Also, what does the `console.log` display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In about you get your json so this json :

```
{
"name" : "Peter",
"surname" : "Chpoksky"
}
```

So to use this object you have to do

```
      <p ng-repeat="post in about">
        {{post.name}}  <!-- To display the name -->
       {{post.surname}}  <!-- To display the surname -->
    </p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked

but I have another question
what which derective I must to write, simply to insert data from a json-file without repeating them?

Comment: This is another question :) if you want more detail make another question or look at angular doc about "$http". If you want to put your json data in a file and get the those data, you have to use $http.get('jsonFile.json',function(data){$scope.data = data; });

Your data in the function will return json object.

Comment: Shoudn't it be post.name and post.surname ?

Comment: You are doing it all wrong. @Okazari is right. Your answer works bcoz `about` is an object and not an array.

Comment: Oups big mistake yes of course, thanks to notice that ! What a shame ... Thanks so notice that, what a shame ..